# Trying to Form auto fill by using jquery - ajax and php-curl

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I've a php webapp where i can create invoices and add clients. for my own convenience i try to implement a feature that when i type in VAT number of a customer the "other" details (like adres, phone number, company name etc.) should auto-fill, load up.

so to achieve this i've put a fa-search-icon next to vat input bar. Whenever someone fills in the vat number and clicks the search icon, jquery handlers an ajax request to a specific php file where i curl a site with the companies vat number. I'm saving the curled page to a html file (the outputis html). The html file containes needed details like adres, phone number etc.

Update NOTE: the values (phone, adres, name) are in html entities format, for example: & # 75; P & #32; & # 68; eco& # 114;

ive put spaced between &# else the code would auto reform to (when you remove all the spaces)KP Decor, so above in html entities KP Decor is written.

i'm not a really pro in this so my question is actually how can i take those values and pass on to my addclient form.

HTML side:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
 <input type="text" id="btwnr" name="client_tax_number" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('placeholder_tax_number'); ?>" />
</div>
<div class="control-label col-md-1">
 <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" id="btwopvragen"></i>
</div>
```

jquery part:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btwopvragen").click(function(){
    var btwnrVal = $("#btwnr").val();
    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "https://www.example.com/FOLDER/FOLDER/btwopvragen.php",
     data: {btwnrVal},
     success: function() {
        $("#bedrijfsnaam").load(
          "http://www.domain.eu/map/540806177.html #StatNameLabel");
     }
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```

php part btwopvragen.php:

```
<?php
$btwnrVal = $_GET['btwnrVal'];
// $btwnrVal = "09999999"; MANUEL TEST
$curlUrl = "https://trendstop.knack.be/nl/detail/".$btwnrVal;

// create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    //opening text File
    $fp = fopen($btwnrVal, "w");

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    //whether to include the header in the curl, set to false.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    //save output to File
    fwrite($fp, $output);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    //closes the txt File
    fclose($fp);
    //prints the output
    // echo $output;
?>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you get in your cURL response? HTML? JSON? XML? Text? Images? You need to create a json response which your PHP-file returns to the ajax function, which just updates the form with the correct values.

Comment: And `$_GET[btwnrVal]` should be `$_GET['btwnrVal']`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the single quotation marks. as for the output it's in html, however the values i want are shown as html values. for example: 

&# 75;P&# 32;&# 68;eco&# 114; if you remove the spaced it auto reforms to KP Decor.

can you elaborate about creating a json and returning to ajax? first time doing this. I tried searching on internet but not much to find.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "html value". Anyway, if you want to get data from a HTML page, you should parse the HTML with [PHP's DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Html entities, ive writen an example in the comment above. Thanks ill check that out.

Comment: There are literally thousands of guides about using ajax, php, json and parsing HTML. If you didn't find any, you haven't searched enough. It's too broad to explain it all. Start searching and learning one thing at the time.

Comment: You're right. there are many recources but i can't find any for my question, maybe i interpret it wrong. as i said before i'm not a pro in these. just a quick question.

isn't this code good for getting a element from another page? 

    success: function() {
        $("#bedrijfsnaam").load(
          "http://www.domain.eu/map/540806177.html #StatNameLabel");
     }
so basically i've an input "bedrijfsnaam" and want to change its value to the value off #StatNameLabel from another html.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the below:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'https://www.example.com/FOLDER/FOLDER/btwopvragen.php',
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(data) {
    $("#btwopvragen").val(data.btw.opvragen);
  }
})
```

This assumes that you have an element with the ID btwopvrageb.

You also don't need `type: GET` as it's the default.